# How to trigger Jquery colorbox close button and close on overlay event

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want to trigger Colorbox event on clicking Close button and overlay close but it's not working:

```
$('#cboxClose').on('click', function() {
alert("Click button");
});
```

---

```
$("cboxOverlay").on('click', function() {
alert("Click overlay");
});
```

Comment: Please post your html markup and the whole script function. And `$("cboxOverlay")` is a wrong selector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use colorbox onClosed callback. See documentation: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

```
$(".popuplink").colorbox({

                href: popupurl,

                close: "Close",

                overlayClose: true,

                onComplete: function () {

                    alert("Completed");

                },
                onClosed: function () {

                    alert("Closed");

                }

            });
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please tick it as a correct answer if it solved your problem.